# Can we decide the instance to pick while using substring?

Tags: java, substring

My data

```
Airline Record Locator 12345
Airline ABC Airlines
```

My substring code

```
 data.substring(data.indexOf("Airline") + ("Airline").length(), data.indexOf("\n", data.indexOf("Airline")));
```

I need to fetch the ABC Airlines data but when I am using the above code, it is fetching me **Record Locator 12345** because it is getting the value Airline in the first line.

Is there any way where we can decide which instance to pick ?

Please suggest ?

Comment: `lastIndexOf()` or pass an offset to `indexOf()`

Comment: Instance of what exactly?

Comment: As you can see in the data above, we have 2 value which starts with the word Airline. I need to extract the second line value but when I am using the above Substring, I am getting the value as Record Locator 12345, that means it is fetching the value from first line.

I wanted to know whether we can decide which value to pick if we have multiple values ? lastIndexOf will not satisfy the criteria here because we might have another line with name "Airline" in the data file.

I tried to use offset but it is not giving me the desired result. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("Airline ") + "Airline".length(), data.indexOf("Airlines")).trim()
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer.